# How do I control the evaluation order of Angular directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive - it enables the jQuery Autocomplete on Angular

```
var myModule = angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
   };
});
```

I have another function

```
$scope.copy_row = function(index) {
    alert($scope.options[index].my_value);
}
```

This gets triggered by the ng-change directive.

Problem is - I want autocomplete directive to fire *before* the ng-change directive.

Works fine on all browsers except for IE. In IE ng-change fires before the autocomplete. I don't want that.

How do I modify this code so that angular fires the autocomplete directive *before* the ng-change directive? It has something to do with setting priority but I don't know how.

Comment: Could you put up some plunker to show us your code and logic?

Comment: Anyway, a quick-n-dirt solution would be to check if the autocomplete directive has been already instantiated when `copy_raw` is called.

Comment: You are probably look for to set the priority of the [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

`priority - When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to set a priority on your custom directive.  The $compile will be called, walks through the DOM and gets all directives.  It then uses the priority to order the directives and then links them.

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive